# Getting only some elements from a Collection

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

My model

```
class A
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<B> Otros {get;set;}
}

class B 
{
    public string At1{get;set;}
    pùblic string At2{get;set;}
}
```

On my repository, I try to get a Collection of A objects, but with ONLY some B objects (filtered by a condition),... but don't works.

Here is the code of my repository (I'm using a Find method from a generic repository, the first arg. is the where clause and the second is a (params) array of includes):

```
return Find(ar => ar.Name == name, // Where
       ar => ar.Otros.Where(oaa => oaa.At1 == at1)); // Include
```

but if I change the above line for this

```
 return Find(ar => ar.Name == name,// Where
           ar => ar.Otros); // Include
```

it works,... but it is not my objective to get ALL the elements on the collection.

Please can anyone explain me how to get only the elements of the collection that have their At1 with a specific value?

NEW INFORMATION:

When I code the below method

```
public IQueryable<AlumnoRegistrado> GetA(string name, string at1)
        {
            return Find(ar => ar.Name == name).Select(ar => new {A = ar, SomeOfB = ar.Otros.Where(oaa => oaa.At1 == at1)})

        }
```

I get the below Error:

> Error 1   No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo
>    'System.Linq.IQueryable' en
>    'System.Linq.IQueryable'. Ya existe una conversión
>    explícita (compruebe si le falta una conversión)
>    C:\Users\jmolina\Source\Workspaces\yyy\Dev\Src\XXX.yyy.Data.EntityFramework.Repositories\A\ARepository.cs    31  17  XXX.yyy.Data.EntityFramework.Repositories

I don't understand why.

Comment: There's *no* way the accented `pùblic` compiles. Make sure the code in this post is accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You need only method that returns IQueryable and introduce new result class to select data:

```
class Result
{
    public A ValueA {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<B> ValuesB {get;set;}
}

public IQueryable<Result> GetA(string name, string at1)
{
    return Find(ar => ar.Name == name).Select(ar => new Result{ValueA = ar, ValuesB = ar.Otros.Where(oaa => oaa.At1 == at1)})
}
```

Comment: I added more information to my question, because when I try to do it, I get a new error.